# log4j2 equivalent for log4j.defaultInitOverride

Tags: configuration, log4j2

Is there any way to tell log4j2 not to automatically load the log4j.configurationFile?

It was possible with log4j1 with "log4j.defaultInitOverride"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of log4j-2.3 no such mechanism exists. All options regarding configuration are described here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration